# How to optimize this complected query?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, query-optimization

While working with following query on mysql, Its getting locked,

```
SELECT event_list.* 
FROM event_list 
    INNER JOIN members 
        ON members.profilenam=event_list.even_loc 
WHERE (even_own IN (SELECT frd_id 
                    FROM network 
                    WHERE mem_id='911' 
                    GROUP BY frd_id) 
           OR even_own = '911' ) 
       AND event_list.even_active = 'y' 
GROUP BY event_list.even_id 
ORDER BY event_list.even_stat ASC
```

The Inner query inside IN constraint has many frd_id, So because of that above query is slooow..., So please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe also add the EXPLAIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT el.* 
FROM event_list el 
INNER JOIN members m ON m.profilenam = el.even_loc 
WHERE el.even_active = 'y' AND 
     (el.even_own = 911 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM network n WHERE n.mem_id=911 AND n.frd_id = el.even_own))       
GROUP BY el.even_id 
ORDER BY el.even_stat ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `GROUP BY` on the inner query, that will be making the database engine do a lot of unneeded work.

Answer (score 0):

If you put `even_own = '911'` before the `select from network`, then if `even_own IS 911` then it will not have to do the subquery.
Also why do you have a `group by` on the subquery?

Also run [explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html) top find out what is taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

This might work better:

```
      ( SELECT  e.*
            FROM  event_list AS e
            INNER JOIN  members AS m ON m.profilenam = e.even_loc
            JOIN  network AS n ON e.even_own = n.frd_id
            WHERE  n.mem_id = '911'
              AND  e.even_active = 'y'
            ORDER BY  e.even_stat ASC )
    UNION  DISTINCT 
      ( SELECT  e.*
            FROM  event_list AS e
            INNER JOIN  members AS m ON m.profilenam = e.even_loc
            WHERE  e.even_own = '911'
              AND  e.even_active = 'y' )
    ORDER BY  e.even_stat ASC
```

Since I don't know whether the JOINs one-to-many (or what), I threw in DISTINCT to avoid dups.  There may be a better way, or it may be unnecessary (that is, UNION ALL).

Notice how I avoid two things that are performance killers:

- OR -- turned into UNION
- IN (SELECT...) -- turned into JOIN.

I made aliases to cut down on the clutter.  I moved the ORDER BY outside the UNION (and added parens to make it work right).